# MySQL find out which WHERE clause was used in select statement

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I've got a `select` statement (below) with multiple `... or ...` connected conditions in my `where` clause, (soon to be 30+ `or` conditions)

What I want to do with this, is to have a column which tells me which `or` in the `where` clause was triggered.

**Is this possible?**

I've tried searching, but I seem to have hit a wall. Any advice or a point in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you

```
select
    Details_TransactionDate as Transaction_Date,
    Details_Credit as Credit,
    MSD.TicketNo as Ticket_Number,
    Details_Pn as Description,
    MSD.Nun as Numbers
from
    MS_Transactions MST
    left join MBS_Details as MSD on MST.TicketNo = MSD.TicketNo
where 
    Details_Pn like '%SALARY%'
    or Details_Pn like '%Mid MTH%'
    or Details_Pn like '%Mid Month%'
    or Details_Pn like '%Pay%'
    or Details_PNarration like '%SAL%'  
        and day(Details_TransactionDate) between 23 and 25
        and weekday(Details_TransactionDate) Between 0 and 4;
```

Comment: "triggered" in what way? Do you mean why a row in the result was included? If so you can just add a bunch of extra expressions to the select, like: `Details_Pn like '%SALARY%' AS passed_condition_1`. _Also, you might want to use parenthesis to force/indicate desired evaluation in the where clause (even if relying on precedence rules.)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for avoid confusion  you should use proper ()  around the OR 
and use proper table anem  Alias  for each column
and you could use a CASE for know which OR is used

```
Select 

    MST.Details_TransactionDate as Transaction_Date,
    MST.Details_Credit as Credit,
    MSD.TicketNo as Ticket_Number,
    MST.Details_Pn as Description,
    MSD.Nun as Numbers,
    case 
      WHEN MST.Details_Pn like '%SALARY%' THEN 'Details_Pn SALARY'
      WHEN MST.Details_Pn like '%Mid MTH%' THEN 'Details_Pn Mid MTH'
      WHEN MST.Details_Pn like '%Mid Month%' THEN 'Details_Pn Mid Month'          
      WHEN MST.Details_Pn like '%Pay%' THEN 'Details_Pn Pay'
      WHEN MST.Details_PNarration like %SAL%' THEN 'Details_PNarrationSAL'
    end or_used 

from MS_Transactions MST
Left join MBS_Details as MSD on MST.TicketNo = MSD.TicketNo

where  ( MST.Details_Pn like '%SALARY%'
OR MST.Details_Pn like '%Mid MTH%'
OR MST.Details_Pn like '%Mid Month%'
OR MST.Details_Pn %Pay%
OR MST.Details_PNarration like '%SAL%'  ) 
AND DAY(MST.Details_TransactionDate) between '23' and '25' and 
    WEEKDAY(MST.Details_TransactionDate) Between 0 and 4;
```